# How to styles checkbox, radio button, dropdownlist by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I want styles my checkbox, dropdownlist follow my style example : transparent background, change color border, change stick sign, change arrow dropdown ... How can i style these controls by javascript ? please give me some advices, solutions or sources to solve it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Styling the native form elements is extremely limited in HTML. You will probably want to look into fully stylable replacements like those offered by http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: I would add that, even if you can style some of the form elements, it will absolutely not behave the same and all the browsers and all the OSes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css

You can use jQuery to manipulate the CSS properties of DOM elements on the client side:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying external skins to your controls.

[Skinnable Form Controls](http://acidjs.wemakesites.net/forms-js.html) lets you do this.